# Distinct roots of the equation $ax^2-bx+c=0$ in $(1,2)$, where $a,b,c\in\Bbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, roots, quadratics

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> If the equation $ax^2-bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots b/w $1$ and $2$ where $a,b,c\in\Bbb{N}$, then show that $a\ge5$ and $b\ge11$.

---

**Attempt at a solution:-**

As the roots are real and distinct then $b^2-4ac\gt0\implies b^2\gt4ac$

Also, as the roots lie in b/w $1$ and $2$, hence $a-b+c\gt0$ and $4a-2b+c\gt0$.

As the roots are greater than $1$, so the product of the roots must be greater than $1$, hence $c\gt a$.

Due to the roots of the equation lying $ax^2-bx+c=0$ in b/w $1$ and $2$, hence $$1\lt\dfrac{b}{2a}\lt2\implies 2a\lt b\lt4a$$.

Now, let's arrange the inequalities in an orderly fashion.
$$b^2\gt4ac\tag{1}$$
$$b\lt a+c\tag{2}$$
$$2b\lt4a+c\tag{3}$$
$$c\gt a \tag{4}$$
$$2a\lt b\lt4a\tag{5}$$

From the above set of inequalities it can be concluded that $a$ will have the smallest value. So, lets start by assigning $a=1$. Then we get the following set of inequalities for $b$ and $c$.
$$b^2\gt4c\\
b\lt1+c\\
2b\lt4+c\\
c\gt1\\
2\lt b\lt4$$

On solving all of these inequalities for $b$ and $c$, we get that there are no natural numbers which satisfy $b$ and $c$ simultaneously.

Going on with this process we find that the first set of natural numbers which satisfy the set of inequalities occurs when $a=5$, which are $b=15$ and $c=11$. And from the inequalities it is pretty clear that this is the least value of $b$ as the bound for $b$ in $2a\lt b \lt 4a$ keeps increasing.

---

**My deal with the question:-**

The question states that the least value of $b$ has to be proven to be $11$ but at that value combined with $c=11\; a=5$ we get a root to be one too. But doesn't the question states that the roots ought to be in b/w the $1$ and $2$, or did I understand the question wrong.

> Also, please do submit your solutions which can teach me something new at high school level.

Comment: First of all, +1 for a nicely worked out question. But please have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748229/consider-the-quadratic-equation-ax2-bxc-0-a-b-c-in-n-if-the-given-equati

Comment: "prove that $a\ge 5$ and $b\ge 11$" means that "prove that $a$ *has to* be larger than or equal to $5$ and that $b$ *has to* be larger than or equal to $11$". It means **neither** $a=5$ is the least *possible* value nor that $b=11$ is the least *possible* value. (of course, $a=5,b=11$ can be the least possible values, but the question does not say anything about this. By the way, $5x^2-11x+11=0$ does not have any real solutions.)

Comment: @mathlove- If both $a=5$ and $b=11$ need not be the least possible values of $a$ and $b$ respectively then why the case of equality is being considered, why not just write $a\gt5$ and $b\gt11$

Comment: @user350331: My understanding is that you are saying that since the question states that "prove that $a\ge 5,b\ge 11$", $a=5,b=11$ have to be possible. If my understanding is correct, then the answer is no, what you are saying is not correct. And the answer to "why not just write $a\gt 5$ and $b\gt 11$" is... that is not our business:) All I can say is that the question is valid even when the least possible values of $a,b$ are $a=1000,b=5000$, and does not say that $a=5,b=11$ are possible.

Comment: For another related question, if you rewrite the equation in $(x-1)$ as:

$$a(x-1)^2 - (b-2a)(x-1) + a - b - c = 0$$

and note that $x-1 \in (0,1)$ then the problem reduces to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010701/distinct-roots-of-ax2-bxc-0-in-0-1-where-a-b-c-in-mathbbz/2011014).